Is there any reason/benefit to Earth Grounding a USB-C Powered Oscilloscope?
I recently bought my first oscilloscope for my hobbyist work (RIGOL DHO804). This oscilloscope is powered through an external USB C Power Supply, meaning that the Oscilloscope GND is isolated from Earth GND. Opening the box and setting up the oscilloscope, I did notice that it did have a port to connect the scope to Earth GND, in case this was something I wanted to have. I do understand that on oscilloscopes that have their power supply internal, the earth ground is for safety, just like with any devices that is powered from mains voltage.
As I'm constantly learning and trying to improve my Engineering knowledge, I wanted to ask what would be the benefit of Earth grounding the oscilloscope here.

I'm sorry -- you're probably excited about your budding Electronics abilities, but you bought the wrong scope.
I hope others can come in and tell me I'm wrong (with evidence), but in my opinion this scope is a hazard and should not be used by anyone, let alone people new to electronics.
The ground of this oscilloscope MUST be grounded at all times.
Usually, battery powered oscilloscopes -- for instance, look at Fluke's Scopemeter -- have fully isolated inputs. You CANNOT touch "ground" on an isolated scope.   Why? It's safety. You, as a user, probably think it's safe to touch your equipment.  With this device, if you don't ground your oscope, you are risking shocking yourself through the OSCOPE "ground" when:

Using a faulty USB PSU
Probing a high voltage line, like probing a current sense resistor that sits on a "LIVE" 120V line.

Anything that can cause your oscope ground to raise up to dangerous voltages puts you at risk.
I suggest returning/exchanging this product for one that is better designed. Just get a desktop OSCOPE with hard-wired ground.
An expert could, potentially, safely use this by being mindful of grounding, the quality of the USB PSU, and the potentials they are probing, but I wouldn't recommend it to anyone.
The only way this can be safe is if the USB PD input power also delivers GROUND, every time, and fault tolerant. I'm not even sure if that's allowed by USB standard, let alone reasonable (12 AWG ground wire is necessary, I think?).  Of course, when you use a gas-station charger, or a battery pack, you would have no ground (and, as I said, potentially lethal voltages from a faulty PSU).

"Usually, battery powered oscilloscopes" ... "have fully  isolated inputs."  Yes, this the key.  From "DHO800_QuickGuide_EN.pdf" : WARNING
This product is a non-isolated oscilloscope. The ground (GND) for each input and output interface is not isolated from the metal chassis or the digital interface grounds . Do not perform floating measurements without using isolated probes, nor connect any port's GND to a port with a voltage difference relative to earth ground. Otherwise, it may cause damage to this product or other devices  can even cause serious personal injury.

So you're saying that even though this oscilloscope can be earth grounded, it's still a danger because it's not a hard wire ground connection? I'm not planning on taking this with me, it's going to stay on my lab bench, so it will always be earth grounded, if it's needed.

", it's going to stay on my lab bench, so it will always be earth grounded, if it's needed."  Better, but does not change the inherent flaw of the scope design.  If you could force a fully-rated chassis ground connection to be present in order for operation, that would be best.

Well in any case, this partly answers my question. So the reason to have it earth grounded is to ensure the oscilloscope isn't floating, for safety?

"for safety?" ...YES, and also that you don't destroy whatever you happen to connect to it (either via the scope inputs, or the USB/HDMI digital connections), like say, your computer.

Remember, there are scopes that are designed to be isolated (and are often battery powered).  They are double insulated, with no exposed metal bits, with specially designed probes and cables.  And a good manual (one would hope).

No. Nothing requires that the scope must be earthed at all times. It might just be a good safety measure when probing unisolated mains for some reason. If you are probing Arduinos powered by batteries, the earthing is rather irrelevant, assuming the Arduino is fully isolated and has no connections to anywhere, other than the floating battery and the scope. There are other reasons to ground it though, such as connecting it to a monitor powered with 2-prong power brick that makes the scope float at half mains due to Y filter caps.

"Nothing requires that the scope must be earthed at all times."  True.  Seatbelts and helmets are optional too; however, highly recommended when learning.  It's all fine, until it isn't.

@ChrisKnudsen If you want to avoid ground loops through scope probes then it might be best to not ground it. That's why lab power supplies have floating outputs, so the supply return does not run through your earthed scope ground clip or earthed PC USB or RS232 cable, inside walls in PE wire back to lab PSU. Same princibles apply here. The HDMI or USBC may already connect to earth potential, or may make scope wiggle at half mains. It might be sometimes best to connect the earth to your probed device for best safety. It always depends, and connecting always to earth is not mandatory.

@ChrisKnudsen, it seems you agree with me? I appreciate the snip from the quick guide about "do not perform floating measurements". I cannot understand why I'd get downvoted. somebody will get hurt. IMO, if you have to ask, this oscope is not safe for you.  and if you're an expert, you're probably not buying this anyways

@J.Street, I'm sorry, if you have to ask, you are not qualified to use this scope.   It's OK until you make a measurement you're not sure of and get (potentially) electrocuted.

The scope potential could be known or unknown depending on where you connect it and how - not only the probes, but everything, including USB-C supply, HDMI display or just the Ethernet cable.
The earthing socket is just for that - connecting the scope ground potential to any potential you want - including earth potential.
You don't know how the USB-C supply, or HDMI display, or Ethernet connect to any potential on the other device. USB-C supply may or may not bond the earth to negative terminal, your HDMI display may have earthed inlet which connects the scope to earth too, or a  2-prong external power supply that makes the scope tingle when you touch it. Also the Ethernet may be bonded to earth via some route or not, for example the infrastructure cabling or via your desktop PC, as it will have the Ethernet metal shell tied to metal chassis which is tied to earth via power supply to mains inlet.
So in case you are measuring something that is also earthed, you can connect the scope ground clip to it and the scope gets earthed too. However, if the HDMI monitor has an annoying 2-prong power brick, and you connect it to scope, the scope ground will float capacitively at 120VAC in reference to earth. That's enough to damage something if the scope ground clip detaches from the board and the tip is probing a sensitive high impedance signal and trying to feed mains AC frequency at some (such as audio going to power amp, it may blow the speaker).
Another thing is safety, if the scope does float, and relatively well without injecting mains hum, and you are probing a circuit with lethal potentials like a power supply, earthing the scope will cause the mains breaker/fuse to blow instead of the scope and everything connected to it becoming live with mains live potential.
So there are things where a floating scope is useful, and there are things where an earthed scope is useful.
You can choose to earth or float the scope depending on what you are doing, but always go through the question if this is a scenario where scope should float or be earthed, and why, is it dangerous to you or for the probed circuit.
The other answer that says the scope must be earthed is false. The scope is never required to be earthed. Just like your USB logic analyzer or any other device connected to a battery-powered laptop is not earthed in any way.
It is of course much better from safety point of view if you ground the scope through the dedicated earthing port than the scope being earthed through USB-C, HDMI or Ethernet ports, if you are doing something that requires the scope to be earthed.
So in order to simulate a standard mains powered desktop scope that gets earthed via mains inlet, I recommend to also earth this scope through the earthing socket.
If you ever need it to be not earthed for some reason, like powering it from a power bank to do some more dangerous measurements later to an unisolated mains power supply where the bulk capacitor negative may wiggle between -325VDC and 0V at mains frequency, at least this scope allows you to do it. Not that you should without clear knowledge of what you are doing, why, how, and what are the dangers of doing it of course.
It's just a scope, as long as you are not jumping straight to unisolated mains voltages, it does not matter much.

With all due respect, this is a dangerous answer. Sure, it is technically correct. But this is an electronics newbie using dangerous equipment.  If they have to ask, they are not qualified to understand statements like "as long as you are not jumping straight to unisolated mains voltages" and "...if you are doing something that requires the scope to be earthed" The user doesn't know.  Would you suggest I buy a desktop OSCOPE and cut the ground prong off to measure something isolated from earth? It's technically doable, and we've all done it, but would you suggest it to a rookie?

@rohmeooo Of course I am not suggesting you to isolate a desktop scope by chopping off the earth connection. That would be a completely different scenario, as a desktop scope will have Y caps from live and neutral to chassis then, making the scope definitely float at half mains. You should never ever use a device with grounded plug in an ungrounded setting. However, this scope with USB-C input has no mains plug and requires no earth, your laptop and many other devices are like this - what's so special about this being an oscilloscope instead of laptop or phone?

The difference is my laptop isn't designed with wires and clips that hang off of it that I'm expected to use to probe electronics, up to 300V with a 10x probe! If i didn't know better, i'd think it's safe to probe my 120V input!  My laptop is meant to be used with other products, hopefully with appropriate UL/etc. designations.  If i plug my laptop USB into some un-isolated un-listed thingy (laptop, AC/DC USB PSU, etc.), my laptop would indeed rise up in voltage and potentially shock me.   It, too, has exposed metal but not nearly as much as an OSCOPE with BNCs sticking out.

I guess, riddle me this: why do Fluke's scopemeters have isolated inputs, isolated charger, isolated comms, and no exposed metal?  Because they like overdesigning?  Or because they realize the huge risk that can occur from what feels like "normal" use?

@rohmeooo OK. If you are a newbie, will you go poking a 300V supply with anything? No, I don't think so. Also, in an ideal world, we would also expect to have monitors that are earthed via power supply, but we don't, we have tingly monitors that can cause damage when hot-plugging them into a computer. So that said, any scope may be earthed via mains plug or separate lead, does it matter? I never said the scope must not be earthed. I simply said what's technically true, it does not need to be earthed for many purposes, but it is safer if it is, sometimes beneficial when it isn't.
